# Is JavaScript object (reference type) returned by reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have code:

```
function Contract() {
  var contract = {};
  contract.id = ...;
  contract.date = ...;

  contract.calculateTotal = function() {
  ...
  }

  return contract;
}
```

The question is - what happens to the result of Contract()? Is contract every time created anew with ={}? This problem is connected with the design of AngularJS model layer. Contract() should be used as constructor for creating new model layer objects. Contract() will be singleton and the **real question is - does every call of Contract() create new object or whether there is one contract object that sits inside singelton Contract() and the same instance is returned in each call of Contract()?**

Comment: this seems easily testable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Each time the `{}` literal is evaluated, it creates a new object, and objects are always handled by reference.

Comment: You're stating "*Contract() will be singleton*", but then asking what happens with `contract = {}` **each time** `Contract()` is instantiated. Doesn't make sense. A *singleton* is an object (design pattern) that can only be instantiated once. There is nothing in your code that's preventing me from instantiating `Contract()` as many times as I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is - what happens to the result of Contract()?

It lives its own life and is not affected by future calls to `Contract`.

> Is contract every time created anew with ={}?

Yes, every time you call the function, the `var` statement creates a new variable.

> Contract() will be singleton

It is not singleton.

> and the real question is - if every call of Contract() creates new object or whether there is one contract object that sits inside singelton Contract() and the same instance is returned in each call of Contract()?

Every call of `Contract()` creates a new object.

#### Singleton

There are several ways to implement singletons. One way is to track the first created instance as a property of the `Contract` function:

```
function Contract() {
  if (Contract.singleton) return Contract.singleton;
  var contract = {};
  contract.id = ...;
  contract.date = ...;

  contract.calculateTotal = function() {
  ...
  }
  // keep a reference in the singleton property of this constructor
  return Contract.singleton = contract;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time your `Contract()` function is called, it will create a new empty object and assign it to `contract` and subsequently will return it from the function.  So, yes, a new instance of the object is returned for each invocation of your function, and yes, it is returned by refernce, so the instance returned is the one created and assigned to `contract` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to test:

```
function contract() {
 contract = {};
 contract.id = 1;
 contract.date = 1991;

 return contract;
}

var contract1 = contract();
var contract2 = contract();

contract1.id = 2;

console.log(contract1); // Object {id: 2, date: 1991}
console.log(contract2); // Object {id: 1, date: 1991}
```

Clearly a new object is created each time you call contract.